# Rust - how can I return error of a different function?

Tags: rust

Given two functions like these:

```
fn foo() -> Result<i32, Box<dyn std::error::Error>> {
    // returns an error if something goes wrong
}

fn bar() -> Result<bool, Box<dyn std::error::Error>> {
   let x = foo(); // could be ok or err
   if x.is_err() {
       return // I want to return whatever error occured in function foo
    }
}
```

Is it possible to return the exact error that appeared in function `foo` from function `bar`?
Also notice, the `Result<T, E>` enum has different `T` in these functions

Comment: Isn't that the exact purpose of [?](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch09-02-recoverable-errors-with-result.html#the--operator-can-be-used-in-functions-that-return-result)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would just let the [? operator](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch09-02-recoverable-errors-with-result.html#the--operator-can-be-used-in-functions-that-return-result) do all the work.

```
fn foo(a: i32) -> Result<i32, Box<dyn std::error::Error>> {
    if a < 10 {
        // returns an error if something goes wrong
        Err(Box::from("bad value"))
    } else {
        Ok(a + 2)
    }
}

fn bar(a: i32) -> Result<bool, Box<dyn std::error::Error>> {
    let x = foo(a)?;
    Ok(x > 5)
}

fn main() {
    println!("{:?}", bar(2)); //  displays Err("bad value")
    println!("{:?}", bar(12)); // displays Ok(true)
}
```